# SCShareableContent.getExcludingDesktopWindows sometimes never calls the completionHandler

Tags: swift, macos, screencapturekit

I have a rather simple piece of code:

```
    private var videoSampleQueue: DispatchQueue? = DispatchQueue(label: "queue.video")

    .....

    func startCapture(_ captureCompletion: StartCapturerCompletion?) {
        
        NSLog("Requesting shareable content")
          
        videoSampleQueue?.async {
            NSLog("Inside video queue")

            SCShareableContent.getExcludingDesktopWindows(true, onScreenWindowsOnly: false, completionHandler: { [weak self] content, error in
                NSLog("Shareable content received")
                self?.processContent(content, error, captureCompletion)
            })

    }
    
}
```

Sometimes (1 of 30 times approximately) the getExcludingDesktopWindows doesn't call the completion handler. It never prints the log 'Shareable content received'. It doesn't fire any error. I can't seem to notice any pattern and what may affect it. I use xCode 14.2, mac os 13.3.1. Any ideas apprecaited.

Comment: Are you sure the getExcludingDesktopWindows is called but not the completion handler?

Comment: @ChristosKoninis yep, I'm 100% sure

Comment: @RossStepaniak What about async throws?

class func excludingDesktopWindows(_ excludeDesktopWindows: Bool, onScreenWindowsOnly: Bool) async throws -> SCShareableContent

Comment: @StevenKoposo Thanks, gonna try it and see if it resolves the issue

Comment: @RossStepaniak Have you fixed the issue? I am having the same issue as it never fires completionHandler

Comment: @StevenKoposov I've tried async throws, the same thing happened - Nothing is happening, no error whatsoever

Comment: @RossStepaniak Were you able to resolve this? I looked at the console logs when this happened and it seems `replayd` daemon was running out of connections/descriptors and restarting the machine fixed the issue.

Comment: I can join you, I'm having the same issue. Restarting replayd did resolve it - faster than restarting the mac. I'll try to figure out if its from xcode debugging or something else.

Comment: @JensPeter "restarting the machine fixed the issue" I found this to be very odd as I thought this was a deadlock issue. Did you call the API once and this happened or call multiple times in an interval?

Comment: @espc I called the ScreenCaptureKit multiple times, maybe 20-30 during debug. I have this happen a few times, were a restart was my only solution, but yesterday killing replayd from Activity Monitor did the same. Sadly, I did not watch the logfiles.

Comment: @JensPeter I called it multiple times as well and for me it was a bit different. When I open up the same app that does call the same API (getExcluding..) multiple times simultaneously, that's when the API gets broken.

Comment: @JensPeter I was having the same issue. The only solution was to run SCShareableContent.getExcludingDesktopWindows after 0.5 sec again if no callback was fired for the first call. Definitely not a good solution but I can't seem to find the cause of this issue

Comment: @RossStepaniak So calling `SCShareableContent.getExcludingDesktopWindows` with a delay was a solution? I know as you said it's not beautiful but I have seen something like this when developing web applications in which I had to use setTimeout to cause a delay on purpose.

Comment: @espc Nope. The idea is: you call SCShareableContent.getExcludingDesktopWindows and fire a delayed selector that will execute in 0.5 sec (not in the completion closure but just before you call getExcludingDesktopWindows). Inside the completion closure of getExcludingDesktopWindows you cancel that selector. This selector just calls SCShareableContent.getExcludingDesktopWindows again. So when completion is called - the selector is cancelled. If completion never calls getExcludingDesktopWindows will be called again. It seems like a primitive and dumb solution, but I don't know the other way.